# Que veut dire « registre des écrous » ici ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, droit-et-justice

Je suis tombé sur un article qui contient cette phrase :

> Dans ce cas, il leur est délivré un extrait du registre des écrous qui vaut justificatif de domicile.

J'ai du mal à comprendre ça, en raison de l'expression « registre des écrous ». Ça veut dire quoi ? Il semble que le mot *écrou* veut dire « *nut* / *screw* » en anglais, ce qui rend la phrase dénuée de sens.

Je suppose qu'il doit avoir une autre signification, particulière au monde juridique. Qu'est-ce que c'est, et d'où vient ce sens ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sur que je suis d'accord, en réflexion, avec votre tag *justice*.  On peut lire [le mot *legal*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9gal) comme un raccourci pour "terminologie légal"; où est la problème?

Comment: Le problème c'est que ça ne veut rien dire, légal est un faux ami.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez OK, je vois.  Que diriez-vous sur *juridique*, avec *legal* et *justice* pour tag synonymes?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, Jez : je confirme que *légal* est un faux ami (en anglais, on dirait *law-abiding* ou *legal* dans le sens de *complying with the law*) ; l'anglais *legal* dans le sens de *relating to the law or a legal process* se traduit plutôt par *juridique*. Cela dit, je ne sais pas s'il faut vraiment des étiquettes différentes. Cela vaut peut-être un message sur [meta.french.se] ; en tout cas, merci de continuer votre tête-à-tête sur le *[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage)*.

Comment: Les autres tags ne sont pas des adjectifs en général, j'hésitais donc plutôt entre « justice » et « droit », mais étant donné qu'il n'y a qu'une question pour l'instant c'est peut-être pas la peine de se casser la tête inutilement et de voir en fonction de ce qui se passe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Au départ, *écrou* (sens 2 dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9crou)) a la même étymologie qu'*écrit*, il me semble. (Il faut remonter assez loin.) Un écrou, c'est un morceau de papier (ou de ce qui en tient lieu à l'époque, un parchemin, voire peut-être un lambeau d'écorce). En français moderne, le mot s'est spécialisé dans le sens d'un morceau de papier sur lequel on note les entrées et sorties d'une prison.
La première édition du [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%27Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) définit le mot ainsi :

> Article du registre des emprisonnements, contenant le jour & la cause pour laquelle on a mis quelqu'un en prison. *Il faut lever vostre escrou & le joindre à vostre requeste. L'arrest porte que son escrou sera rayé et biffé.*
>   Il se dit aussi, Des rolles de la despense de bouche de la maison du Roy. *Les escrous ne sont pas encore signez, arrestez*.

À noter qu'il n'y a aucun lien étymologique avec le sens plus courant d'écrou que l'on monte sur une vis, même si le rapprochement sémantique (un écrou maintient une vis et une pièce en place) a peut-être contribué à la spécialisation du mot.

Le *registre d'écrou* (plus courant, je crois, que *registre des écrous*) est donc le cahier dans lequel sont notés les emprisonnements. Plus généralement, c'est la base de données des prisonniers.

Le mot *écrou* n'est pas du vocabulaire courant. Par contre, on utilise plus usuellement le verbe *[écrouer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9crouer)* dans le sens d'emprisonner.

Answer (score 6):

[Écrouer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9crou) est un verbe utilisé dans le langage courant pour « l'acte de mettre en prison ». Un exemple typique :

> Ils ont été écroués.

Une recherche rapide sur le web ne semble pas suffire pour trouver une définition qui inclut un sens similaire pour « écrous »… Ah en fait si, voir la définition de [écrou](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9crou) sur Wikipedia… Il s'agit du terme employé dans le monde judiciaire pour désigner l'acte (procès-verbal) qui accompagne une incarcération.

Comment: Ce n'est pas l'acte préalable à une incarcération, mais un acte concommittant. Voir la deuxième définition du TLF.

Comment: @Gilles: ok, je veux bien le croire, je ne suis pas très calé en jargon judiciaire :-)